# MPMoviePlayerController has no response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player 
    = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:video_url];

[[player view] setFrame : [ib_image_base_view bounds]];

[ib_image_base_view addSubview : [player view]];

[player play];
```

Above are the 5 statements I am using to play a video file.  The video_url has value : 
"Intro_00.mp4 -- file://localhost/" as echoed by a NSLog statement.  Its value is initialized as : video_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"Intro_00.mp4"];

The problem is the MoviePlayer is not having any response, there is no error or warning message from Xcode either.  The 5 lines of code are part of an iPhone project.

Hope somebody can give some hints.

(*** for some reasons stackoverflow's "add comment" does not work at the moment)

Comments are added below ...

Have tried the following as suggested, but still no response.

```
[player setControlStyle: MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
```

Update 1 :

Have found out that the video_url is "null" all along.  So I find and download a related sample project from Apple.  But the same problem seems to persist.  For details please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728863/mpmovieplayercontroller-and-the-nsurl-object).

Update 2 :

@Eduardo has found the solution to both questions.  So this question should be closed.  Thanks for the kind assistance and response from all who have look into my post :)

Comment: have you tried another URL (perhaps one not locally) just to make sure?

Comment: Solution given to [MPMoviePlayerController and the NSURL object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728863/mpmovieplayercontroller-and-the-nsurl-object) also applies to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"Intro_00.mp4"]` and remember to add the file to the bundle (Project Build Steps > Copy Resources)

Answer (score 1):

Here one sample code is available .... it is help to u.....

[**Download Movie Player Source Code**](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
[player setControlStyle: MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

Before Playing video have to include MediaPlayer.framework and import header files

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:videoURL];

moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

[moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: @Stanley:is that working now?If you have any issues then you can surely share here.Then only we can help you

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as my internet link was not in good order.  Now I've found out that the video_url is (null) all along.  So I find and download a related sample project from apple.  But the same happens except the "m4v" sample video file which come with the sample project.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728863/mpmovieplayercontroller-and-the-nsurl-object

Answer (score 0):

Also try adding `[moviePlayer prepareToPlay]` before calling `play`.